# CardLayout - How to Delete current card (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

How would one delete the current card that the user is on. I know how to go through a card layout using the next and previous function, but how would one remove the current frame that the user is on? For example, if I have a program where I am currently on the 3rd panel out of 5 total panels, how would I delete the current one which is the 3rd panel. Once you remove it, the next or previous one replaces it. I do not think removecurrentlayout can be used cause I am not removing a component. For example, in the code, how would I go about delete Card 3 if I am on that.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;  
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CardLayoutProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
        final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          JButton card = new JButton("Card " + i);
          card.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
          String cardName = "card" + 123123;
          cardPanel.add(card, cardName);
        }

        contentPane.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        nextButton.addActionListener(e -> cardLayout.next(cardPanel));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: `String cardName = "card" + 123123;` Why is the code adding cards with the same name, in a loop? More widely, why do you see the need to delete a card? What is supposed to appear there once it *is* deleted?  The solution might be as simple as to add a blank `JPanel` and flip to it once the user decides it is time to 'delete' the existing card (without actually removing the card) it might be that the best action is to simply change the values shown in any controls in the card back to default values (e.g. information is committed to storage)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `CardLayout` does not tell you which card (JPanel) is currently being displayed.

Check out [Card Layout Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) for a class that extends the `CardLayout` to provide this functionality.

You would use the `getCurrentCard()` method to access the panel currently being displayed.

Then once you get the card currently being displayed you can remove it from the parent panel using by the `remove(...)` method of the `Container` class.

You would just use the class as follows:

```
//final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
final RXCardLayout cardLayout = new RXCardLayout();
```

The logic for your "Remove" button would be:

```
cardPanel.remove(cardLayout.getCurrentCard());
```

Comment: *Is this maybe a version dependend feature?* - it's an extension of the CardLayout found at the link provided in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the docs for [`Container`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), you will see that it has a `remove()` method. Since [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) extends `Container`, it also has this method. You should familiarize yourself with these API docs to find this kind of information.

Answer (score -1):

When you say index(3rd panel of 5 panels), you mean the name (String) of the component when it was inserted, right? I don't know any elegant way to do this, but you can try to get all the components in this container (parentComponent) and try to find the one that has the same name as your index. For example:

```
Component[] components = parentComponent.getComponents();

for(int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
    if(components[i].getName().equals(index)) {
        cardLayout.removeLayoutComponent(components[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) the CardLayout manages the name internally. It is a constraint that is used when the card is added to the panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for information on how the layout manager works.